# Problem with service created to change network parameter at system start

Tags: linux, networking, services

I have created a script to put the network card to 1G when the system starts. I have created a new service for this but it doesn't works.

I execute the start and I get this error and the speed of network doesn't change.

```
$ systemctl start service activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service
Failed to start service.service: Unit service.service not found.
$
```

This is my .service file (I have probed the with the 3 After that I put hear)

```
cat activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service
[Unit]
Description=Activa1GRed
#After=multi-user.target
#After=network.target 
After=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The sh file is (If I execute manually it works fine)

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 433 nov 22 22:43 /usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh

$ cat /usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Cambiamos la velocidad de la tarjeta a 1Gb
/usr/sbin/ethtool -s enp3s0 autoneg on
```

Edit:

With **systemctl start activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service** the services works fine manually but when I reboot the machine it doesn't works and i get this error

```
$ systemctl status activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service
● activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service - Activa1GRed
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-11-23 02:34:11 CET; 3min 4s ago
    Process: 1185 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1185 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 11ms

nov 23 02:34:05 aqua systemd[1]: Starting Activa1GRed...
nov 23 02:34:06 aqua activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh[1189]: netlink error: failed to retrieve link settings
nov 23 02:34:06 aqua activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh[1189]: netlink error: No such device
nov 23 02:34:11 aqua systemd[1]: activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service: Succeeded.
nov 23 02:34:11 aqua systemd[1]: Finished Activa1GRed.
```

How can delay the execution of my service until the network is up?

Edit2:

I have followed your instructions and the startup has been stopped 2 minutes waiting for the network. After that the system has boot but 1G configuration doesn't works. **The speed is 100Mb/s** after boot.

```
    Settings for enp3s0:
...
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
...
        Link detected: yes
enp3s0: 100 Mbit, half duplex, link ok
```

After boot I run manually the start of service

```
    $ systemctl start activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service
    $ systemctl status activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service
    ● activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service - Activa1GRed
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-11-23 23:06:53 CET; 3s ago
    Process: 5891 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    nov 23 23:06:48 aqua systemd[1]: Starting Activa1GRed...
    nov 23 23:06:53 aqua systemd[1]: activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service: Succeeded.
    nov 23 23:06:53 aqua systemd[1]: Finished Activa1GRed.
```

and now I have the correct speed **(1000Mb/s)**

```
Settings for enp3s0:
...
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
...
        Link detected: yes
enp3s0: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok

       Main PID: 5891 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
            CPU: 11ms
```

This is the output of dmesg command for enp3s0

```
$ dmesg|grep enp3s0
[    2.168785] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[    4.401733] systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
[    9.127366] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   11.801640] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[   11.801647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[  129.159287] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[  131.368490] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Half - flow control off
[  414.549164] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[  417.332359] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl start service activar_a_1G_enp3s0.service


                ^^^^^^^
```

There's your problem - get rid of that `service`.

Edit1: attempt at helping with the changed requirements.

Try the following:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

And in your unit file add:

```
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Of course I can't guarantee that that works - the order of events under systemd can be a bit fickle.

Comment: Now, if I execute it manually it works, but when execute at startup fails. I think that it occurss because my script is executed before that network is up, but I don't kown how can I delay the execution until the network is up.

Comment: @estonolose - can you try the suggestions in the edit?

Comment: I have updated with edit2, thanks